# Two-dimensional string array creation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create two-dimensional array of 1-character strings in javascript this way:

```
var panel = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('*'));
```

Result is

```
[
    ['*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*']
]
```

After that I need to replace middle string:

```
panel[1][1] = '#';
```

And the result is

```
[
    ['*', '#', '*'],
    ['*', '#', '*'],
    ['*', '#', '*']
]
```

So it seems that prototype `fill` function fills array with object by reference.

Is it possible to force `fill` function to fill array with different object instances?
If no, what approach of creation this-like two-dimensional array in your opinion is the best?

---

**Update**

Algorithm assumes to create a plane of asterisks, and then a lot of those asterisks will be replaced with another symbols creating some reasonable result. After that it will be printed.

In `C` it could be done using matrix of `char`s and changing symbols at any indices.
But as far as we cannot simply change single symbol in javascript string, I'm trying to find some good analogue.

Currently I've created two-dimensional array using two loops, then changing symbols I need, and after that with `map` and `join` functions I'm joining this result to a single string. But is it the best solution?

Thank you.

Comment: just to be clear...that result is your desired output?

Comment: @jordanhendrix No, that result is real javascript result. Desired output is with only one '#' string in the middle of the matrix.

Comment: @YuraYakym let me know if my solution helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not sure about the efficiency of this method** but Converting the array into string using `JSON.stingify()` and then parsing back to original format by `JSON.parse()` makes the objects loose its original reference and work without any pain.

```js
var panel = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('*'));
var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(panel));

copy[1][1] = '#';

//you can assign the value of variable 'copy' back to 'panel' if required.

document.write(JSON.stringify(copy)); //for demo
```

You can simplify the above logic into single liner of code without extra variable, this way

```js
var panel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('*'))));
panel[1][1] = '#';

document.write(JSON.stringify(panel)); //for demo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a dirty fix, but I'll give it anyway:

```
var panel = new Array(3).fill(new Array(3).fill('*'));
panel[1] = [panel[1][0],"#",panel[1][2]];
console.log(panel);

/*
Result:
[
    ['*', '*', '*'],
    ['*', '#', '*'],
    ['*', '*', '*']
]
*/
```